# MKClusterAnnotation causing EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift

[image: Storyboard]

I have a navigation controller with two view controllers, one of them with an `MKMapView`.
Outlet and delegate are set.

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.delegate = self
}
```

Delegate method `mapView(_:viewFor:)` returns an `MKMarkerAnnotationView` that can be clustered.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let annotationView = MKMarkerAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "_")
    annotationView.clusteringIdentifier = "_"
    return annotationView
}
```

If the following conditions match, when the view controller is popped from the navigation controller, Xcode raises EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

1. There must be at least one `MKClusterAnnotation` on the map.
2. There must be at least one annotation selected on the map.

[image: MKMapView]

In the situation above, tapping the back button or swiping from the left edge triggers EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

This can be avoided by deselecting any selected annotations in `viewWillDisappear(_:)`, but I'm not sure if this is the ideal solution.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    for annotation in mapView.selectedAnnotations {
        mapView.deselectAnnotation(annotation, animated: true)
    }
}
```

I would like to know why the exception is raised.

Comment: post your full crashlog

Comment: Did you tried to enable exception breakpoints?